# Modifing an object by another class

Tags: c++, oop, reference

My purpose is to change the tank (an object of first class) by another class (the odometer). So I try to passing by reference, its working when I pass directly object to constructor but its doesn't working when I make an object first then passing object by a method(setOdoIndex). Can someone have a way to do make a method to pass these parameters

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;


    class FuelGauge {
    protected:
        double galls;
        double check(double) const;
        double checkFuel(double) const;
    public:

    FuelGauge(double galls){
       check(galls);
       this->galls = galls;
    }

    FuelGauge(){
        *this = FuelGauge(0);
    }

    double getFuelLeft() const{
         return galls;
    }

    FuelGauge operator++(){
          if (galls > 15) throw "Tank max capacity is 15 gallon";
          ++galls;
    
          return *this;
    }

    FuelGauge operator--(){
        if (galls == 0) throw "Tank is empty";
        --galls;
        return *this;
    }

    void refuel(){
        galls = 15;
    }

};

    double FuelGauge::check(double n) const {
        if (n < 0) throw "Dont accepted negative value!";
        if (n > 15) throw "Tank max capacity is 15 gallon";
        return n;
    }

    class Odometer{
        private:
           int odo;
           FuelGauge &tank;

           void calOdo() {
               if (odo > 999999) {odo = 0;};
           }

         public:

            Odometer(int odo, FuelGauge &tank):tank(tank) {
                this->odo = odo;
                this->tank = tank;
            }

            Odometer():tank(tank) {
                odo = 0;
            }

            int getOdoIndex() const{
               return odo;
            }

            void setOdoIndex(int odo, FuelGauge &tank) {
               this->odo = odo;
               this->tank = tank;
            }

            void carDrive() {
               --tank;
               calOdo();
               ++odo;
            }
        };


       int main() {
            FuelGauge tank;

            cout << "--Fill the tank--" << endl;
            try {
               for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
               ++tank;
               }
            }
            catch(const char* e) {
               cerr << e << '\n';
            }

            cout << "\n--Car run--" << endl;
            Odometer odo1(0, tank);

            try {
                for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                cout << "Index of odometer: " << odo1.getOdoIndex() << endl;
                cout << "Fuel left: " << tank.getFuelLeft() << endl;
                odo1.carDrive();
                }
             }
             catch(const char* e) {
             cerr << e << '\n';
             }

             return 0;
             }
```

Comment: Strange design.  Odometers only measure distance although some may be combined to show speed also.  Never had the odometer connected to the fuel tank or fuel tank meter.

Comment: You can replace the tank filling loop in `main` with `tank.refill();`.

Comment: You should refresh your understanding of initialization list.  If you have `tank` in the initialization *list*, you don't need `this->tank = tank;` in the constructor.

Comment: If you use a different coding standard, you don't need to use the `this->` syntax.  For example, some people prefix member names with `"m_"` and others append an underscore.  You only *need* the `this->` syntax to differentiate parameter names from member names.

Comment: IMHO, your default constructor should not call another constructor.

Comment: IMHO, the `FuelGauge::check` method should return a boolean.  It's a yes/no, or true/false kind of function.  Besides, comparing double for equality is a pain.

Comment: In your `Odometer()` method, where is the `tank` parameter that you use in the initialization list?

Comment: Are you sure this code compiles correctly?

Comment: Yes, this code compiles correctly. Is there any situation that a class modify another object ?. Like passing reference to a function